# Newton's Method for finding Complex Roots in Java

Tags: java, newtons-method

I got a project in my Java class which I'm having trouble with.
The project is basically marking coordinates on the screen, making a (complex) polynomial out of them, then solving the polynomial with Newton's method using random guesses and drawing the path of the guesses on the screen.
I don't have a problem with any of the drawing, marking, etc.
But for some reason, my Newton's method algorithm randomly misses roots. Sometimes it hits none of them, sometimes it misses one or two. I've been changing stuff up for hours now but I couldn't really come up with a solution.
When a root is missed, usually the value I get in the array is either converging to infinity or negative infinity (very high numbers)
Any help would be really appreciated.

```
> // Polynomial evaluation method.  
   public Complex evalPoly(Complex complexArray[], Complex guess) {
        Complex result = new Complex(0, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < complexArray.length; i++) {
            result = result.gaussMult(guess).addComplex(complexArray[complexArray.length - i - 1]);
        }
        return result;
    }

> // Polynomial differentation method.
    public Complex[] diff(Complex[] comp) {
        Complex[] result = new Complex[comp.length - 1];
        for (int j = 0; j < result.length; j++) {
            result[j] = new Complex(0, 0);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length - 1; i++) {
            result[i].real = comp[i + 1].real * (i + 1);
            result[i].imaginary = comp[i + 1].imaginary * (i + 1);
        }
        return result;
    }

> // Method which eliminates some of the things that I don't want to go into the array
    public boolean rootCheck2(Complex[] comps, Complex comp) {
        double accLim = 0.01;
        if (comp.real == Double.NaN)
            return false;
        if (comp.real == Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY || comp.real == Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY)
            return false;
        if (comp.imaginary == Double.NaN)
            return false;
        if (comp.imaginary == Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY || comp.imaginary == Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY)
            return false;
        for (int i = 0; i < comps.length; i++) {
            if (Math.abs(comp.real - comps[i].real) < accLim && Math.abs(comp.imaginary - comps[i].imaginary) < accLim)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

> // Method which finds (or attempts) to find all of the roots
  public Complex[] addUnique2(Complex[] poly, Bitmap bitmapx, Paint paint, Canvas canvasx) {
        Complex[] rootsC = new Complex[poly.length - 1];
        int iterCount = 0;
        int iteLim = 20000;
        for (int i = 0; i < rootsC.length; i++) {
            rootsC[i] = new Complex(0, 0);
        }
        while (iterCount < iteLim && MainActivity.a < rootsC.length) {
            double guess = -492 + 984 * rand.nextDouble();
            double guess2 = -718 + 1436 * rand.nextDouble();
            if (rootCheck2(rootsC, findRoot2(poly, new Complex(guess, guess2), bitmapx, paint, canvasx))) {
                rootsC[MainActivity.a] = findRoot2(poly, new Complex(guess, guess2), bitmapx, paint, canvasx);
                MainActivity.a = MainActivity.a + 1;
            }
            iterCount = iterCount + 1;
        }
        return rootsC;
    }

> // Method which finds a single root of the complex polynomial.
    public Complex findRoot2(Complex[] comp, Complex guess, Bitmap bitmapx, Paint paint, Canvas canvasx) {
        int iterCount = 0;
        double accLim = 0.001;
        int itLim = 20000;
        Complex[] diffedComplex = diff(comp);
        while (Math.abs(evalPoly(comp, guess).real) >= accLim && Math.abs(evalPoly(comp, guess).imaginary) >= accLim) {
            if (iterCount >= itLim) {
                return new Complex(Double.NaN, Double.NaN);
            }
            if (evalPoly(diffedComplex, guess).real == 0 || evalPoly(diffedComplex, guess).imaginary == 0) {
                return new Complex(Double.NaN, Double.NaN);
            }
            iterCount = iterCount + 1;
            guess.real = guess.subtractComplex(evalPoly(comp, guess).divideComplex(evalPoly(diffedComplex, guess))).real;
            guess.imaginary = guess.subtractComplex(evalPoly(comp, guess).divideComplex(evalPoly(diffedComplex, guess))).imaginary;
            drawCircles((float) guess.real, (float) guess.imaginary, paint, canvasx, bitmapx);
        }
        return guess;
    }

> // Drawing method
    void drawCircles(float x, float y, Paint paint, Canvas canvasx, Bitmap bitmapx) {
        canvasx.drawCircle(x + 492, shiftBackY(y), 5, paint);
        coordPlane.setAdjustViewBounds(false);
        coordPlane.setImageBitmap(bitmapx);
    }

}
```

Comment: Should be noted that `== Double.NaN` is always false. You should use `Double.isNan(double)` to see if a value is NaN.

Comment: So it's making random guesses and you're missing the roots? That's not surprising. You are taking a stab in the dark at x. Newton's method works by looks at one x that produces a positive y and another x that produces a negative y and then bisecting the difference.

Comment: @rajah9 That's how we've been taught. The same method was working without a problem for normal polynomials. The random guess would always eventually converge to a root. I'm struggling to understand what you mean by the second part, an example would be appreciated.

Comment: @rajah9: That is the bisection method. While it is robust as a bulldozer, if the conditions apply, it is also as slow. Newton is the Ferrari that might be more delicate to handle but is also magnitudes faster. -- Further, the bisection method does not easily apply to functions on the complex plane.

Comment: Thanks, @LutzL, you helped me learn something new.

Answer (score 0):

### Error 1

The lines

```
guess.real = guess.subtractComplex(evalPoly(comp, guess).divideComplex(evalPoly(diffedComplex, guess))).real;
guess.imaginary = guess.subtractComplex(evalPoly(comp, guess).divideComplex(evalPoly(diffedComplex, guess))).imaginary;
```

first introduce a needless complication and second introduce an error that makes it deviate from Newton's method. The `guess` used in the second line is different from the `guess` used in the first line since the real part has changed.

Why do you not use, like in the evaluation procedure, the complex assignment in

```
guess = guess.subtractComplex(evalPoly(comp, guess).divideComplex(evalPoly(diffedComplex, guess)));
```

---

### Error 2 (Update)

In the computation of the differentiated polynomial, you are missing the highest degree term in

```
for (int i = 0; i < result.length - 1; i++) {
   result[i].real = comp[i + 1].real * (i + 1);
   result[i].imaginary = comp[i + 1].imaginary * (i + 1);
```

It should be either `i < result.length` or `i < comp.length - 1`. Using the wrong derivative will of course lead to unpredictable results in the iteration.

---

### On root bounds and initial values

To each polynomial you can assign an outer root bound such as

```
R = 1+max(abs(c[0:N-1]))/abs(c[N])
```

Using `3*N` points, random or equidistant, on or close to this circle should increase the probability to reach each of the roots.

But the usual way to find all of the roots is to use polynomial deflation, that is, splitting off the linear factors corresponding to the root approximations already found. Then a couple of additional Newton steps using the full polynomial restores maximal accuracy.

---

### Newton fractals

Each root has a basin or domain of attraction with fractal boundaries between the domains. In rebuilding a similar situation to the one used in

[image: original location of roots produced by program]

I computed a Newton fractal showing that the attraction to two of the roots and ignorance of the other two is a feature of the mathematics behind it, not an error in implementing the Newton method.

[image: Newton fractal for a similar root distribution]

Different shades of the same color belong to the domain of the same root where brightness corresponds to the number of steps used to reach the white areas around the roots.

Comment: It was that way originally, I think I've changed it later to test something and left it that way. Sadly, the result is still the same. I'll link an image of the app. The circles with black dots in it are unfound roots. http://imgur.com/v9ncxT3

Comment: Could you emphasize the initial points of the iterations, by color or size? Or connect the points of each iteration with lines? Each root has a basin or domain of attraction that contains a disk around the root and usually has a fractal boundary where all basins mix, as one can see by looking for "Newton fractals".

Comment: Thanks for the informative reply! It'll take me a while to read and understand everything, math really isn't my thing sometimes. In this picture the initial guesses are the bigger pink circles. http://imgur.com/HqDn8WU

Comment: I made it so that the program takes the biggest and smallest values for all X and Y values given and randoms between those numbers. I'm still missing a lot of roots. http://imgur.com/eV3mT1O

Comment: Last thing I tried is choosing the random values individually very close for each root. Even when the initial guess is pixels away from the root, it fails to converge sometimes.http://imgur.com/vY7BuR3

Comment: I might have misinterpreted the screen shot. There was another programming error, to be found in the section "Error 2 (Update)".

Comment: Damn, I feel stupid. That was indeed the problem. Thanks a lot for everything though, I've learnt more than I thought out of a simple mistake. I really appreciate you taking the time to explain everything one by one!